# $(function() não funciona

Tags: javascript

sou iniciante nesta linguagem e tenho a seguinte dúvida:
 o código abaixo está funcionando, porém se tiro o comentario da parte *** Com este bloco não funciona***, ele passa a não funcionar, mas preciso dele para ativar um calendário em um outro fonte que tenho. Existe alguma forma de o mesmo funcionar sem que o bloco  saia da body e o script do datepicker permaneça na head?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html">
    <meta charset= "UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>Consulta de Apartamento</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_gerais.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/retorno_consulta.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>      
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.4.0.min.js"></script>      
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- *** Com este bloco não funciona***
  <script type="text/javascript">      
        $(function() {$( ".data" ).datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: none,
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changerYear: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            dateFormat:  'dd/mm/yy',
            dayNames:['Domingo','segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
            dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sab','Dom',],
            monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto',
            'Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro',],
            monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez']});});
      </script> -->
</head>
<body>

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnTestar").click(function(){
      alert("Hello, World.");
    });
});
  </script>
<form>
  <button id="btnTestar">Testar</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Está carregando o jQuery 2 vezes. Apague `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>` e coloque aspas em `none`: `buttonImage: "none",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você percebeu que está carregando as versões 2.2.3 e 1.10.1 do jQuery?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Removendo o carregamento da versão 1.10.1 o código parece funcionar, ao menos aparece a janela de alerta e o console deixa de dar erro.

Ah, creio que seja `null` ao invés de `none` em **buttonImage**.

Comment: Funcionou!! era só remover uma das verões.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro ponto: Voce esta utilizando um pluguin do jQuery UI que seria uma outra library da qual depende do jQuery para funcionar.

Verifique a compatibilidade da versao do jQueryUI para com a do jQuery.

Como ja falado, vc esta utilizado de 2 versoes do jquery simultaneamente, decida qual seria a melhor apropriada, ou mais compativel com o resto do codigo.

Esteja certo de que o codigo do datepicker esteja realmente funcionando, pois independentemente do lugar na qual este esteja instanciado, no header ou dentro do Script fora do header, este deve funcionar.

Caso tudo de errado, comece do zero:
Va ao site do jquery UI baixe a versao stable.
Pegue um exemplo de uso do datepicker e aplique na pagina.

Tente organizar melhor como os scripts sao carregados,
jQuery sempre em primeiro em relacao aos outros scripts.
Seu css sempre por ultimo aos externos.

O codigo do datepicker depende de um elemento que acredito ser um Input com a classe data para poder funcionar tambem, entao, esteja certo de que este, ao ser descomentato, nao ira funcionar realmente.

Referencia: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Funcionou!! era só remover uma das verões.